# Why is my freezer making a very loud buzzing noise after being unplugged for a few days?

Tags: appliances, noise

My freezer was unplugged for a few days and now when I plug it in it makes a very loud alert kind of buzzing noise.  It isn't just the noise it makes regularly.

It is a loud, almost alarm-like noise that is very worrisome. What could it be? How can I get it to stop?

Comment: Is this a chest freezer or part of a fridge/freezer? Did it defrost completely?  I used to get fan noise from ice buildup.

Comment: Is the freezer still chilling down; or is it still making noise despite having reached normal operating temperature?

Comment: It might also be useful to mention what make/model the freezer is. Is the noise continuous or intermittent? If the latter, is it regular? Could it be the compressor is having to work hard to bring the freezer back under control?

Answer (score 1):

Some freezers have an alarm so that you know that the internal temperature rose to an unsafe level for any food stored in it - for example if there was a long power outage whilst you were out of the house.